# Pagination not working in laravel 5.3 with for loop iteration. Pagination object is being hide when i use for loop or foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Pagination is working without use of for loop, when want to do structuring with data using for or foreach loop, pagination is being hide from response. here is my code. Pagination object is being hide when i use for loop or foreach loop.

```
 $calls = DB::table('call')
            ->where('call.company_id', '=', $company_id)
            ->orderBy('call.created_at', 'ASC')
            ->paginate($perPage, array( $columns ), 'current_page', $currentPage);

            $lead = new Lead();
            $i = 0;
            for($i=0; $i < count($calls); ++$i){

                $callData = ""; 
                $callData['id'] = $calls[$i]->id;
                $callData['date'] = $calls[$i]->date;
                $callData['duration'] = $calls[$i]->duration;
                $callData['user_id'] = $calls[$i]->user_id;
                $callData['contact_number'] = $calls[$i]->contact_number;
                $callData['from_time'] = $calls[$i]->from_time;
                $callData['call_type'] = $calls[$i]->call_type;
                $callData['created_by'] = $calls[$i]->created_by;
                $callData['created_at'] = $calls[$i]->created_at;
                $callData['updated_at'] = $calls[$i]->updated_at;

                 $callsData[] = $callData;
                }

                return $callsData;
```

Comment: you are using datatables??

Comment: No i have written method in model for restful api and calling that method on controller.

Comment: you are writing apis for android app??

Comment: yes I am writing api for android app.